# Idiomatic way of merging arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops

Given i have two arrays that look like this:

```
array1 = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
]

array2 = [:a, :b]
```

What is the best way to combine them into a new array that looks like:

```
[
  [1, 2, :a],
  [3, 4, :b],
]
```

I was hoping there's a way to do this without iterating over one of the arrays and using it's index to grab an element from the other array... Is there a better more ruby way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
array1.zip(array2).map(&:flatten) #=> [[1, 2, :a], [3, 4, :b]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(array1.transpose+[array2]).transpose
  #=> [[1, 2, :a], [3, 4, :b]]
```